# Laravel : Search by min and max value from the table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am confuse about search with `min-max` value.In my `posts` table there is a two field `min_price` and `max_price`, on my search there is a couple of thing which I need to covered in search query.

1. If user search with only `max_value`, it shows all the posts which price is `less than or equal to max_value`.
2. If user search with only `min_value`, it shows all the posts which price is `less than or equal to min_value`.
3. If user search with `min_value` and `max_value`, it shows all the posts which price is between `min_value and max_value`.
4. If both null, return all posts.

How can I do this ?

My code:

```
$searchablePost = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
                 ->whereIn('product_id', $userApprovalProductIDs)
                ->whereIn('demand_or_supply', $demand_or_supply);

// skip my search query code

$searchedPost = $searchablePost->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

How can I do t

Comment: For `min_value` criteria is same *less than or equal to min_value* are you sure ? i guess it should be greater or equal

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid for case 2 ?

Comment: Yes for second case

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yes if search within `min_price` only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Check:**
**1.** if both (min & max values) are available (i.e. not null):
**2.** if min value is available:
**3.** if max value is available:

```
// if none of them is null
if (! (is_null($min_value) && is_null($max_value))) {
    // fetch all between min & max values
    $searchablePost = $searchablePost->whereBetween('price', [$min_value, $max_value]);
}
// if just min_value is available (is not null)
elseif (! is_null($min_value)) {
    // fetch all greater than or equal to min_value
    $searchablePost = $searchablePost->where('price', '>=', $min_value);
}
// if just max_value is available (is not null)
elseif (! is_null($max_value)) {
    // fetch all lesser than or equal to max_value
    $searchablePost = $searchablePost->where('price', '<=', $max_value);
}
```

---

If you have separate fields for `min_price` & `max_price`, as mentioned in comment, just change the code as following:

```
if (! (is_null($min_value) && is_null($max_value))) {
    $searchablePost = $searchablePost
                      ->where('min_price', '>=', $min_value)
                      ->where('max_price', '<=', $max_value);
}
elseif (! is_null($min_value)) {
    $searchablePost = $searchablePost->where('min_price', '>=', $min_value);
}
elseif (! is_null($max_value)) {
    $searchablePost = $searchablePost->where('max_price', '<=', $max_value);
}
```

Comment: on case:1 what if I have a both value `min_value` and `max_value` .? should i compare it to only price ? As there is two different field in my table.min_price and max_price

Comment: it's client requirement.

Comment: you mean there are total of 3 fields for price: (price, min_price & max_price) ???

Comment: In my posts table there is a two field min_price and max_price.I Didn't talk about 'price'.

Answer (score 1):

You can set $min = 0; and $max = infinite_choosen_number; and append whereBetween method to your query, like the below code:

```
$searchablePost = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
    ->whereIn('product_id', $userApprovalProductIDs)
    ->whereIn('demand_or_supply', $demand_or_supply)
    ->whereBetween('price', ["$min", "$max"])->get();
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a whereIn, you can do that with a where statement.
Something like this

```
`
$searchablePost = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
                 ->whereIn('product_id', $userApprovalProductIDs)
                ->whereIn('demand_or_supply', $demand_or_supply)
->where('price', '>=', $minPrice)
`
```

Didn't try it so int might fail but here is the way to do it.